# eslint command fails on CI Server with error "ESLint couldn't find the config "standard" to extend from"

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have eslint configuration which works perfectly fine on my local setup (with vscode editor).

but on CI Server, it fails with following error:

```
  eslint:config-array-factory Config file found: /home/worker/workspace/-CI-CD-Pipeline-Node-Ts_DC-705/.eslintrc.json +0ms
  eslint:config-array-factory Loading {extends:"standard"} relative to /home/worker/workspace/-CI-CD-Pipeline-Node-Ts_DC-705/.eslintrc.json +1ms

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 6.6.0.

ESLint couldn't find the config "standard" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "standard" was referenced from the config file in "/home/worker/workspace/-CI-CD-Pipeline-Node-Ts_DC-705/.eslintrc.json".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.
```

I am running following command to lint:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./ --ext .ts`

I see there are multiple issues on git related to this (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/696) but none has solution or that did not worked for me.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: Have you checked that you're installing the [eslint-config-standard](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard) npm dependency in your CI environment?

Comment: yes, I confirmed its available @AlessandroCifani

Comment: Same issue appeared with my "airbnb" config on the CI server only. Same version of eslint. First thing to make sure is that there's not a global `eslint` that's being executed instead of the one from your devDependencies (use ```npm run-script eslint``` or write a `lint` command in package.json that calls `eslint` to use the locally bundled executable). There's a good discussion here about some of the reasons for the error. https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/465 . I am still having the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that eslint-config-standard-with-typescript isn't installed.

Try this:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint@7 eslint-plugin-promise@4 eslint-plugin-import@2 eslint-plugin-node@11 @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4 eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
```

Answer (score -1):

To disable eslint during build you can add this code to *.config file as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-eslint)

```
module.exports = {
    eslint: {
            ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
}
```

it helped me remove the error

Comment: very bad practice to disable eslint-ing on a typescript production project.